# replace all text urls with html url

Tags: regex, r

I have a text file containing urls that 'd like to replace with `a` tags that open into a new tab.  I'm converting the .txt file to a .md file and want clickable links.

I have shown below (1) a MWE, (2) desired output (3) my initial attempts to create a function (I assume this will/could take `gsub` and the `sprintf` function to achieve):

**MWE:**

```
x <- c("content here: http://stackoverflow.com/", 
    "still more", 
    "http://www.talkstats.com/ but also http://www.r-bloggers.com/", 
    "http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/404.html"
)
```

** Desired output:**

```
> x
[1] "content here: <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">http://stackoverflow.com/</a>"                                                     
[2] "still more"                                                                                  
[3] "<a href="http://www.talkstats.com/" target="_blank">http://www.talkstats.com/</a> but also <a href="http://www.r-bloggers.com/" target="_blank">http://www.r-bloggers.com/</a>"                               
[4] "<a href="http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/404.html" target="_blank">http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/404.html</a>"
```

**Initial attempt to solve:**

```
repl <- function(x) sprintf("<a href=\"%s\" target=\"_blank\">%s</a>", x, x)
gsub("http.", repl(), x)
```

One corner case for using `"http.\\s"` as the regex is that the string may not end in a space as in `x[3]` or the url is contains to `http` which wouldn't only want to parse one time (as seen in `x[4]`).

**PLEASE NOTE THAT *R's* REGEX IS SPECIFIC TO R;

ANSWERS FROM OTHER LANGUAGES ARE NOT LIKELY TO WORK**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works with your sample `x`, and using your `repl` method:

```
gsub("(http://[^ ]*)", repl('\\1'), x)
```

or without your `repl` method:

```
gsub("(http://[^ ]*)", '<a href="\\1" target="_blank">\\1</a>', x)
```